# How to cast a ListBoxItem to the class bound to the list?

Tags: wpf, listboxitem

I have a ListBox with a list of Buddies bound to the class Buddy {String name; String message}

When the user clicks an item I get the clicked item by handling the PreviewMouseDown event:

```
var item = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(lb, e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as ListBoxItem;
```

The problem is that I cannot convert item to Buddy item: if I try to cast with

```
Buddy b=(Buddy)item
```

I get an error like cannot convert type ListBoxItem to Buddy

How can I make a cast to Buddy class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it should be actually...

```
Buddy b = (Buddy)item.DataContext;
```

Does this help?

Comment: great! this was the solution !!

Answer (score 2):

The DataContext property on the ListBox item will be the Buddy that the item is bound to. Use this instead.

```
Buddy b=(Buddy)(item.DataContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the wrong way to access the items (and use WPF). You should handle the SelectionChanged event, then cast the SelectedItem to a Buddy type. That's the object involved in the selection.

Comment: I've used SelectionChanged, the problem is that i need to handle click on the item even when it is already selected.

Comment: Okay, when the PreviewMouseDown is triggered, on the handler do the same as was fired the SelectionChanged. The SelectedItem still give the actual item.